# Zencoding abbreviation - php injection

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, emmet

This is cool, and you all know that:

```
div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a
```

When I hit 'tab' it yields out in a nice html-formatted code. And I like that of course. I am a lazy coder, which would love coding to be easier. I would like to know if there is a php-engine that helps out with this in runtime. As for example

```
$clickLabel = array('Link 1', 'Link 2', 'Link 3' ,'Link 4', 'Link 5');
$pageTemplateID = 'myPageID';

// outputs html-tags with correct data
zenEcho('div#{$pageTemplateID}>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*{len($clickLabel)}>a{$clickLabel}');
```

I think you might grasp what I am looking for. I think this would be great in certain cases. Sure there is better approaches to seperate content and structure then this.. but I have many projects with agile development in which does require quick coding and progress.

And I believe this part of the Zen coding would make a good effort. 
Of course this solution would probably be taking som time in execution at runtime.. but nevertheless ;)

Do you know of a php-script like this - that combines the Zencoding abbreviation but as a php function? It would be cool, or?

Thanks